# Date Picker : Rest on next select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using a [package](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker). Specifically [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#view-mode).

Everything works fine, I clicks on the date picker, I selects year, Then month and then date, And the picker closes.

But when it closes and i click on it again, Only the last day calendar shows, Meaning it doesn't starts over again from year.

What i want is that, It should starts over again from year to month to day.

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4dc2fbj/60/)

Here is my code :

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker9'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Js :

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'years'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the datetimepicker issue tracker, [issue 1897](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1897) there is a suggestion for a workaround.

Basically you add a timeout that resets the datetimepicker to years mode once it's been used once.

```
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'years'
  });

  $('#datetimepicker9').on('dp.hide', function(event){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#datetimepicker9').data('DateTimePicker').viewMode('years');
    },1);
  });  
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1oqpLz5d/)